# Repeatedly clicking while holding left mouse button down

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been working on an c# auto clicker for a while and I've been stopped by a problem. 
I want my auto clicker to repeatedly press LMB meanwhile I'm holding down mouse button 1(left). 
The way I've made this is :

```
    private void GlobalHookMouseDownExt(object sender, MouseEventExtArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            AutoClick.Start();
    }

    public void autoclick()
    {
      while(true)
        {
          mouse_event(0x02,(uint)Cursor.Position.X,(uint)Cursor.Position.Y,0,0); //LMB DOWN
          Thread.Sleep(100);
          mouse_event(0x04,(uint)Cursor.Position.X,(uint)Cursor.Position.Y,0,0); //LMB UP
            Thread.Sleep(1000); //1 click per second
        }
    }
```

It starts checking if I press LMB, if I do so it will start the autoclick thread, then that thread will send a mousebutton down and then mousebutton up  event, canceling my check. Even though I'm still holding down on my mouse, nothing happens. 
What am I doing wrong? If you have a better way of doing this please let me know.

Comment: "It starts checking if I press LMB" - actually you check `MouseButtons.Middle`.  Try press it

Comment: I modified it, still doesn't work.

Comment: My suggestion - you need to put some delay between `DOWN` and `UP`

Comment: Done, but that still doesen't fix my problem :(

Comment: I assume this is a reduced set. Where do you stop the Autoclick timer/thread/backgroundthread? Better, post your real code as the error is somewhere else (And I assume it's because you terminate the clicker thread on the mouse up event, which you are firing from the autoclick routine).